# In pandas dataframes, how would you convert all index labels as type DatetimeIndex to datetime.datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Just as the title says, I am trying to convert my DataFrame lables to type datetime. In the following attempted solution I pulled the labels from the DataFrame to dates_index and tried converting them to datetime by using the function DatetimeIndex.to_datetime, however, my compiler says that DatetimeIndex has no attribute to_datetime.

```
dates_index = df.index[0::]
dates = DatetimeIndex.to_datetime(dates_index)
```

I've also tried using the pandas.to_datetime function.

```
dates = pandas.to_datetime(dates_index, errors='coerce')
```

This returns the datetime wrapped in DatetimeIndex instead of just datetimes.

My DatetimeIndex labels contain data for date and time and my goal is to push that data into two seperate columns of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick solution to my problem. You can create a new pandas column based on the index and then use datetime to reformat the date.

```
df['date'] = df.index   # Creates new column called 'date' of type Timestamp
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p')  # Date formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `DateTimeIndex` is `myindex`, then

`df.reset_index()` will create a myindex column, which you can do what you want with, and if you want to make it an index again later, you can revert by `df.set_index('myindex')

Answer (score 0):

You can set the index after converting the datatype of the column.

To convert datatype to datetime, use: `to_datetime`
And, to set the column as index use: `set_index`

Hope this helps!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mydatecol': ['06/11/2020', '06/12/2020', '06/13/2020', '06/14/2020'],
    'othcol1': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'othcol2': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})
print(df)
print(f'Index type is now {df.index.dtype}')
df['mydatecol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydatecol'])
df.set_index('mydatecol', inplace=True)
print(df)
print(f'Index type is now {df.index.dtype}')
```

Output is

```
    mydatecol  othcol1  othcol2
0  06/11/2020       10        1
1  06/12/2020       20        2
2  06/13/2020       30        3
3  06/14/2020       40        4
Index type is now int64
            othcol1  othcol2
mydatecol                   
2020-06-11       10        1
2020-06-12       20        2
2020-06-13       30        3
2020-06-14       40        4
Index type is now datetime64[ns]
```